# EF Core Owned types - The entity type cannot be added to the model because a weak entity type with the same name already exists

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm facing issues with Migrations when I use the same class as owned type in different entities.
If I generate an initial migration with the following code, it works properly, but when I try to generate a second one, it throws the error: The entity type 'OwnedTypesTests.AddressDetails' cannot be added to the model because a weak entity type with the same name already exists.

EF Core version 2.2.6

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace OwnedTypesTests
{
    public class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDbContext>().UseSqlServer(TestDbContext.ConnectionString).EnableSensitiveDataLogging().EnableDetailedErrors().Options;
            using (var dbContext = new TestDbContext(dbOptions))
            {
                dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

                Console.WriteLine("Test");
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public const string ConnectionString = "-";

        public DbSet<PersonType1> PersonType1s { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PersonType2> PersonType2s { get; set; }

        public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options) : base(options) {}

        public TestDbContext(){}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var pType1Builder1 = modelBuilder.Entity<PersonType1>();
            pType1Builder1.ToTable("person_type_1");
            pType1Builder1.HasKey(p => p.Id);
            pType1Builder1.OwnsOne(p => p.Address, c =>
            {
                c.ToTable("Address1");
                c.Property<int>("Id");
                c.HasKey("Id");
                c.Property(a => a.Street).HasColumnName("street_name");
                c.OwnsMany(a => a.ListOfDetails, a2 =>
                    {
                        a2.ToTable("list_details_1");
                        a2.HasForeignKey("address1_id");
                        a2.Property<long>("id");
                        a2.HasKey("id");
                        a2.OwnsOne(l => l.From).Property(p => p.Code).HasColumnName("from_code");
                        a2.OwnsOne(l => l.To).Property(p => p.Code).HasColumnName("to_code");
                    });
            });

            var pType1Builder2 = modelBuilder.Entity<PersonType2>();
            pType1Builder2.ToTable("person_type_2");
            pType1Builder2.HasKey(p => p.Id);
            pType1Builder2.OwnsOne(p => p.Address, c =>
            {
                c.ToTable("Address2");
                c.Property<int>("Id");
                c.HasKey("Id");
                c.Property(a => a.Street).HasColumnName("street_name");
                c.OwnsMany(a => a.ListOfDetails, a2 =>
                {
                    a2.ToTable("list_details_2");
                    a2.HasForeignKey("address2_id");
                    a2.Property<long>("id");
                    a2.HasKey("id");
                    a2.OwnsOne(l => l.From).Property(p => p.Code).HasColumnName("from_code");
                    a2.OwnsOne(l => l.To).Property(p => p.Code).HasColumnName("to_code");
                });
            });
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString).EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        }
    }

    public class PersonType1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonType2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address1
    {
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public List<AddressDetails> ListOfDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public List<AddressDetails> ListOfDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddressDetails
    {
        public Location From { get; set; }
        public Location To { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```